# Minimize MAE loss for a target that is sum of two other targets

Tags: regression, predictive-modeling, xgboost, loss-function, gradient-descent

Working on a regression modelling task where my dataset have some feature columns, two more columns A, B and a target column T. The goal is to predict T, and minimize MAE, that is `mean(|T_actual - T_predict)|`. My question is about how to reformulate my modelling/learning task.

I have a target variable T, that is not intuitive and hard to model. However, I know that `T = A + B`, where both A and B and intuitive and easier to model (I know how to create meaningful features for them). Thus instead of modelling T, I want to create 2 models - one for A and one for B, and in the end sum them up hoping to minimize

`mean(|T_actual - T_predict|) = mean(|A_actual + B_actual - A_predict - B_predict|)`

The simplest thing I could do was:

- when training a model for A: I chose again the MAE objective and minimized `mean(|A_actual - A_predict|)`
- when training a model for B: I chose again the MAE objective and minimized `mean(|B_actual - B_predict|)`

Finally, my predictions for target T are `T_predict = A_predict + B_predict`. However, I get very bad predictions and MAE for target is very large. This is probably because MAE is not additive and

`mean(|A_actual+B_actual - A_predict - B_predict|) != mean(|A_actual - A_predict|) + mean(|B_actual - B_predict|)`.

My question, is what objectives can I use when training models for A and B, so that MAE for target T is optimized?

Not sure if it matters, but the model I use is a gradient boosting model (gbm) `xgboost.XGBRegressor` and it has built in MAE objective. I was thinking if somehow I could train the two gbms for A and B in parallel and update the loss function `mean(|A_actual+B_actual - A_predict - B_predict|)` but am not sure how would that even be implemented.